# Conditional LEAD/LAG with no sequence guarantee

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

How does one write a conditional lead/lag where the preceding or proceeding lead/lag isn't guaranteed to satisfy a certain condition?  In my case, I'm looking at website traffic.

Sample data (prior_path and prior_event are the target fields of which I'm having trouble getting to prior_event given my conditions)

```
+-----------+-----+-------+---------------------------------------+-------+------------------------------------+-------------+
| sessionid | hit | type  |                 path                  | event |             prior_path             | prior_event |
+-----------+-----+-------+---------------------------------------+-------+------------------------------------+-------------+
|      1001 |   1 | event | www.stackoverflow.com                 | hover |                                    |             |
|      1001 |   2 | page  | www.stackoverflow.com                 |       |                                    | hover       |
|      1001 |   3 | event | www.stackoverflow.com                 | load  |                                    |             |
|      1001 |   4 | event | www.stackoverflow.com                 | blur  |                                    | load        |
|      1001 |   5 | event | www.stackoverflow.com                 | click |                                    | blur        |
|      1001 |   6 | page  | www.stackoverflow.com/post/10         |       | www.stackoverflow.com              | click       |
|      1001 |   7 | event | www.stackoverflow.com/post/10#details | offer |                                    |             |
|      1001 |   8 | page  | www.stackoverflow.com/post/confirm    |       | www.stackoverflow.com/post/10      | offer       |
|      1001 |   9 | page  | www.stackoverflow.com/questions/10    |       | www.stackoverflow.com/post/confirm | offer       |
|      1001 |  10 | event | www.stackoverflow.com/questions/10    | exit  |                                    |             |
+-----------+-----+-------+---------------------------------------+-------+------------------------------------+-------------+
```

prior_path:  last path where type = page for only page hit types
prior_event: last event where type = event for all hit types

Notice for hit 8 and 9, the "offer" event gets repeated because those led to those pages.

prior_path seems straight-forward as I can do

```
SELECT LAG(path) OVER (PARTITION BY sessionid, type ORDER BY hit) FROM my_table
```

but I'm not sure how to get prior_event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right expression for `prior_path` already. You just need to wrap it in a conditional expression.

As for `prior_event`, it is a bit more complicated indeed. I would suggest the following approach:

- for events, we can just use `lag()`
- for pages, an option is to use some gaps-and-islands technique: first define groups with a conditional sum that increments every time an event is met, and then use `first_value()`:

This should do what you want:

```
select  
    t.*,
    case when type = 'page'
        then lag(path) over(partition by sessionid, type  order by hit)
    end prior_path,
    case type 
        when 'page'
            then first_value(event) over(partition by sessionid, grp order by hit)
        when 'event' 
            then lag(event) over(partition by sessionid order by hit)
        end prior_event
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        sum(case when type = 'event' then 1 else 0 end) 
            over(partition by sessionid order by hit) grp
    from mytable t
) t
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=db01c179542b274ffeaeee2ed74f7e79)** (due to the lack of hive fiddle in the wild, I used Postgres - but this would work on Hive as well):

```
sessionid | hit | type  | path                                  | event | grp | prior_path                         | prior_event
--------: | --: | :---- | :------------------------------------ | :---- | --: | :--------------------------------- | :----------
     1001 |   1 | event | www.stackoverflow.com                 | hover |   1 | null                               | null       
     1001 |   2 | page  | www.stackoverflow.com                 | null  |   1 | null                               | hover      
     1001 |   3 | event | www.stackoverflow.com                 | load  |   2 | null                               | null       
     1001 |   4 | event | www.stackoverflow.com                 | blur  |   3 | null                               | load       
     1001 |   5 | event | www.stackoverflow.com                 | click |   4 | null                               | blur       
     1001 |   6 | page  | www.stackoverflow.com/post/10         | null  |   4 | www.stackoverflow.com              | click      
     1001 |   7 | event | www.stackoverflow.com/post/10#details | offer |   5 | null                               | null       
     1001 |   8 | page  | www.stackoverflow.com/post/confirm    | null  |   5 | www.stackoverflow.com/post/10      | offer      
     1001 |   9 | page  | www.stackoverflow.com/questions/10    | null  |   5 | www.stackoverflow.com/post/confirm | offer      
     1001 |  10 | event | www.stackoverflow.com/questions/10    | exit  |   6 | null                               | null
```

Comment: Works like a charm!  Thanks for the explanation and the reference to the gaps-and-islands technique.  That's a new one for me so I appreciate the reference for additional research.

Comment: Is there a way to get this to work for getting the leading event for page?  E.g. Similar to getting "offer" for both hit 8 and 9 for prev_event, can it be reworked to get the "exit" event for hit 10 as next_event for hit 8 and 9?  In the outer select, I tried a combination of LEAD and LAST_VALUE, but that didn't quite work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need `lag()` and some conditional logic:

```
select . . .,
       (case when type = 'page'
             then lag(path) over (partition by sessionid, type order by hit)
        end) as prior_path,
       lag(event) over (partition by sessionid order by hit) as prior_event
from my_table;
```